# Yammer API - Modify group settings

Tags: http-put, yammer

Yammer REST API documentation: http://developer.yammer.com/restapi/

The only documentation on groups is on joining and leaving a group.  But I know there are many more group-related APIs, such as listing all groups, getting all messages in a group, etc.  So my question is, is it possible to modify group settings via the API?  I.e. change the group name, change the description, change between Public and Private, and change who can join?

I tried the following...

I have a class `Group` that mirrors the group data in Yammer.  So:

```
Group groupInfo = new Group();
groupInfo.id = groupId;
groupInfo.name = name.ToLower();
groupInfo.full_name = name;
groupInfo.description = description;
groupInfo.privacy = "private";
groupInfo.show_in_directory = "false";

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", AccessToken));

    StringContent content = new StringContent(groupInfo.ToJSON(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.PutAsync(quri, content);

    string queryResult = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = response.Result.StatusCode;
}
```

But the resulting status code was 400 (Bad Request).  So I don't know if my PutAsync request wasn't formatted correctly or whether it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this, but it is not supported. Group management apps create a poor experience for users of Yammer. Applications submitted to the Yammer App Directory may not be accepted if they attempt to manage groups in a Yammer network.

You are converting your group to a JSON representation. Instead of doing this specify the parameters on the URL. Only a few items can be changed like  name (string), private (true or false), listed (true or false) etc.